# Mac OS X set terminal name that persists after SSHing somewhere else

Tags: macos, mac, ssh, terminal

I try advice [like this](http://thelucid.com/2012/01/04/naming-your-terminal-tabs-in-osx-lion/) that recommends adding the following to your .profile:

```
function tabname {
    printf "\e]1;$1\a"
}
```

So you can type `tabname brokenbox` to name your tab. The problem is as soon as I also type `ssh djechlin@dandandan.net` and log in, it wipes the tab name. I want a tab name that's as persistent as the tab, not the level of session I happen to be in. Is this possible? I don't even know what layer that data lives in.

Answer (score 1):

The new Title is probably being set in part of your start scripts on the machine you're ssh'ing to.

You'd probably have to edit your startup files on the remote server, and have it check to see if you're coming from ssh.  You could check if your bash shell is descended from a sshd process.  Or `who am i` might help you.

The simpler fix is just to reset the title once you log in, though this will work only if the remote shell changes the title just once. If it changes it on every cd (very common) then you need to edit the startup files.